# Open Image in a frame using javacv 1.4.2

Tags: java, swing, opencv, frame, javacv

I am new to javacv and want to know how to open the image in a frame using javacv 1.4.2 and opencv 3.4.2.

I have downloaded both opencv and javacv, and extracted it into C drive. Also loaded it into Libraries.

This the code i tried.

```
Mat image = imread(filename);
    if (image != null) {
        GaussianBlur(image, image, new Size(3, 3), 0);
        imwrite(filename, image);
    }
```

I just want to show the image in the frame before saving it to the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code block for show Mat in frame.

```
public static void showResult(Mat img)
{   
    MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
    Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", img, matOfByte);
    byte[] byteArray = matOfByte.toArray();
    BufferedImage bufImage = null;
    try
    {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
        bufImage = ImageIO.read(in);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bufImage)));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey i got following error when i tried your code:                                     incompatible types: org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.Mat cannot be converted to org.opencv.core.Mat. Any suggestion to make it correct?

Comment: Why don't you try using OpenCV java build?

Comment: @seokrae.kim You to build it from source for all the systems you want to use it on, javacv is just a maven repo.